# Detect what value to use for scroll positions javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-browser

I was fiddling around on a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smartguy1196/x8cozgo3/) and I discovered a potential issue. Within the fiddle, I have a logger setup to track the position of the scroll if the site is embedded in a iframe (which it is on jsfiddle). However, I need to be able to detect with javascript which value I used would be appropriate for tracking scroll position within an iframe across all browsers. I used the values:

`window.scrollTop`

`document.documentElement.scrollTop`

`document.body.scrollTop`

The fiddle's js:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",
  function() {
    console.log(
      "window:" + window.scrollTop + 
      "; documentElement:" + document.documentElement.scrollTop + 
      "; body:"+ document.body.scrollTop
    );
  }
);
```

The fiddle's CSS:

```
html{ height : 300% }
```

Using Chrome, I get logs that are similar to:

`window:undefined; documentElement:0 (always 0); body:[some number] (variable number-actual scroll)`

**NOTE: in response to charlieftl's comments** I need to make a script that will detect which of the three values I listed is appropriate for tracking the scroll position.

Also, the purpose of the script is to get the appropriate scroll position based upon whether the website is iframed(embedded) or not. When it is not the appropriate value is window.scrollTop, but inside an iframe it seems to be document.body.scrollTop. Also, I need to know when it is appropriate to use document.documentElement.scrollTop.

**NOTE:** jQuery solutions are appreciated, but native javascript is preferred.

Comment: Totally unclear what objective is regarding iframe or what the problem is

Comment: @charlietfl explain. I asked how do I detect which value to use. what's confusing?

Comment: demo works the same no matter what browser i try. It doesn't seem to replicate any problems

Comment: That wasn't the point. It works, I just need to know which value will get me the correct scroll position when the site is iframed (embedded). The problem I am concerned about is that when you access my site, window.scrollTop is the value to use, but inside the iframe it is document.body. I also need to know when it would be required to use document.dcoumentElement instead @charlietfl

Comment: @charlietfl I also updated the question

Comment: a window inside iframe is not any different than main window with regard to code within it

Comment: You are not going to get the parent page's scroll position through the iframe's scroll position. You would have to read the parent's, not the iframes. And you can only do that if it is the same origin.

Comment: @charlietfl really? is that so? then why does window return `undefined`?

Comment: @espascarello I don't think you understand. I am trying to get the scroll position of the iframe when the site is iframed/embedded. I am used `window`, because I am not sure if the iframe would be considered a window.

Comment: @charlietfl I like how my daughter was able to answer faster than you did. You guys with high rep should stop commenting and start answering or you just get beat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I am nice, I went and tested this fiddle on several browsers (except Opera-for what ever reason I can't download it).

I found that your script logs a value for `document.documentElement.scrollTop` when it is in IE and Firefox. While in Chrome, it logs the value for `body.scrollTop`. IE, Chrome, and Firefox all log `undefined` for the `window.scrollTop` value.

Therefore, window.scrollTop is useless for the iframed content. But just for the sake of the case that this is not true in Opera, I made this code:

```
window.scrollTo(0,20);
document.documentElement.scrollTo(0,20);
document.body.scrollTo(0,20);

/* ^^these scroll values are only temporary */

if(isset(window.scrollTop) && window.scrollTop=20)
  alert("use window as object");

if(isset(document.documentElement.scrollTop) && document.documentElement.scrollTop=20)
  alert("use documentElement as object");

if(isset(document.body.scrollTop) && document.body.scrollTop=20)
  alert("use documentElement as object");

window.scrollTo(0,0);
document.documentElement.scrollTo(0,0);
document.body.scrollTo(0,0);

/* ^^default the scroll value back to normal state */
```

**NOTE:** However, I would be wary of using window, because it may be actually referencing the parent window and not the iframe -don't quote me on this. I am not very familiar with iframes, I was just playing around with your fiddle

Comment: I like how Kaye with only 28 points rep was able to answer here before the commenters @charlietfl and epascarello with over 50,000. Good job Kaye!

Comment: @espacarello that is for you too